# xstream CannotResolveClassException

Tags: java, xstream

I'm trying to use xstream 1.4.2 to convert xml to object. It does work perfectly fine for me until I put the object's class file in a separate package than where the main code runs. Then I get a CannotResolveClassException. I've tried using the setClassLoader method as recommended by others but that doesn't help.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: result
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:56)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:45)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:133)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1052)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1036)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:912)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:903)
at main.readClass(main.java:48)
at main.main(main.java:28)
```

**Answer:** xstream expects the xml structure to be relative to the package in which it (the object) originates from. So xstream.alias must be used in order to alias the xml structure.

```
xstream.alias("something", Something.class);
```

Otherwise xstream will expect "Something" to be in the default package rather than the package it is a member of.

Comment: Package? What do you mean by package?

Comment: can you post the xml and the java class you are using to populate

Comment: The fully qualified name works well `xstream.alias(...)`, but how does it work with Annotations ?

Answer (score 7):

When you pass the class name to the alias method you need to pass the fully qualified class name i.e the class name along with its package name.

Example : Suppose if the class Something is in the package com.xyz then you need to pass com.xyz.Something.class as the parameter

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your question it will be useful

**Download Xtream.jar**

```
package businessfunctions;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import objectrepository.LoginPojo;
import objectrepository.LoginPojos;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver;

    public void readRepository(String fNmae){

        // Instantiate XStream Object
        XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver()); 

        // Set Person class into xstream alias
        xstream.alias("loginpojos",LoginPojos.class);
        xstream.alias("loginpojo",LoginPojo.class);

        xstream.addImplicitCollection(LoginPojos.class, "loginpojos");

        // Create a StringBuffer var
        StringBuffer contents = new StringBuffer();

         try {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                // Set BufferReader var "in" to read from PersonXML.xml file
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(repoPath+fNmae));

                String str;

                while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                contents.append(str);
                }

                in.close();

             } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
             }
            // Checking the StringBuffer variable "contents"
            System.out.println(contents);

            String content = new String();

            // Put all the contents from contents to String variable content --xstream.fromXML()takes
            //only String
            content = contents.toString();

            // Convert content into XML and change and set to obj newPerson of class Person
            LoginPojos loginPojosList = (LoginPojos)xstream.fromXML(content);

            List<LoginPojo> loginPojoList = loginPojosList.getLoginpojos();
            for(LoginPojo newLogiPojo:loginPojoList){
            // Print out the newPerson properties
            System.out.println("Property Label: " + newLogiPojo.getPropLabel());
            System.out.println("Property Name: " + newLogiPojo.getPropName());
            System.out.println("Property Value: " + newLogiPojo.getPropValue());
            }

             }



public static void main(String args[]) {
         try {
             DriverSetup ds= new DriverSetup();
             ds.readRepository("login.xml");  

         }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(); 
         }

package objectrepository;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class LoginPojos {

     public List<LoginPojo> loginpojos = new ArrayList<LoginPojo>();

    public List<LoginPojo> getLoginpojos() {
        return loginpojos;
    }

    public void setLoginpojos(List<LoginPojo> loginpojos) {
        this.loginpojos = loginpojos;
    }



}


package objectrepository;

public class LoginPojo {

    private String propLabel;
    private String propName;
    private String propValue;
    public String getPropLabel() {
        return propLabel;
    }
    public void setPropLabel(String propLabel) {
        this.propLabel = propLabel;
    }
    public String getPropName() {
        return propName;
    }
    public void setPropName(String propName) {
        this.propName = propName;
    }
    public String getPropValue() {
        return propValue;
    }
    public void setPropValue(String propValue) {
        this.propValue = propValue;
    }



}


<loginpojos>
<loginpojo>
<propLabel>User name1</propLabel>
<propName>id1</propName>
<propValue>username1</propValue>
</loginpojo>
<loginpojo>
<propLabel>User name</propLabel>
<propName>id</propName>
<propValue>username</propValue>
</loginpojo>
</loginpojos>
```

Comment: yes, this  not resolve my problem but it's useful.Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Spent half an evening trying to resolve similar error. 
Passing a driver to xStream miraculously helped.

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a mismatch of names. Sender had ConfigWiFi and receiver defined WiFiConfig.