# CannotResolveClassException using XStream

Tags: java, web-services, xstream

i am using xstream to serilaize the response getting from the restfull web service call.
But when i hit the web serrvice URL and while wrapping that response to xml, i am getting the following expection:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: response
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:56)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:45)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:133)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1058)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1042)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:913)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:904)
```

can any one help me ti get out of this problem.
any helping hands would really gratefull.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15730399/1862502

Comment: possible duplicate of [xstream CannotResolveClassException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438124/xstream-cannotresolveclassexception)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438124/xstream-cnnotresolveclassexception look at this.

Comment: i tried with all the ways waht you suggested above. but i am getting the same problem.any other ways to get rid of it.

Comment: You don't get a block of debugging info just before the stacktrace?