# Java XStream Cannotresolveclasscastexception - where to put which alias?

Tags: java, xstream

I have a project which I need to debug, and I get a `Cannotresolveclasscastexception` due to some `XStream` error.

In this thread: [xstream CannotResolveClassException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438124/xstream-cannotresolveclassexception), I read that in that case one should add an xstream alias, however I have no clue what for, and what the alias needs to be. A minimal code example is:

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;



public class Configuration
{
    private static final Configuration ourInstance = new Configuration();
    private ConfigData ourData;
    //original private XStream xStream = new XStream(new DomDriver()); // does not require XPP3 library
    private XStream xStream = new XStream();
    private String configFileDirectory = "C:\\";   
    private String mainConfigurationFile = "MainConfiguration.xml";


    private Configuration()
    {
        // Private to ensure singleton status
    }

    /**
     * Load configuration information.  This method must be called before calling any other
     * methods.
     */
    public static void load()
    {
        ourInstance.loadConfiguration();
    }

    private void loadConfiguration()
    {
        ourData = (ConfigData)loadObject(mainConfigurationFile);
    }

    private Object loadObject(String fileName)
    {
        Object obj = null;
      try
        {
            obj = fromFile(fileName);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);  // Can't continue without a configuration object

        }
        return obj;
    }

    private Object fromFile(String fileName) throws IOException
    {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(configFileDirectory + fileName);
        return (Object) xStream.fromXML(reader);
    }

    private static class ConfigData
    {

    }
}
```

and calling function:

```
public class test_main_blabla {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration.load();
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.alias.CannotResolveClassException: data.Configuration$ConfigData : data.Configuration$ConfigData
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.DefaultClassMapper.lookupType(Unknown Source)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.ReferenceByXPathMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(Unknown Source)
    at Configuration.fromFile(Configuration.java:56)
    at Configuration.loadObject(Configuration.java:42)
    at Configuration.loadConfiguration(Configuration.java:34)
    at Configuration.load(Configuration.java:29)
    at test_main_blabla.main(test_main_blabla.java:4)
```

Could anybody help me by getting this minimal code example to work?

Would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the *exact* error you're receiving. It should show the name it can't resolve.

Comment: oh yes, just updated the post. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you just need your `ConfigData` class to be public?

Comment: no, that doesn't help

Comment: I assume your `Configuration` class really is in a `data` package? It would help if you could show your XML too - and ideally a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: currently its in the default package, but as far as I know that doesn't change anything, does it?
Also, the XML also doesn't even matter for this, since it gets the error before doing anything with it... So I'd say this is the complete part where the problem lies...

Comment: Well it does when xstream is trying to resolve `data.Configuration$ConfigData` and that class doesn't exist...

Comment: but then what to do about it?

Comment: rather: No, its not! thats why I have to set an alias, right? but what is this alias supposed to look like?

Comment: Well, what does the documentation say about aliases? http://x-stream.github.io/alias-tutorial.html